# what to do if i can't access my Magento admin path, it directs me to other blog

Tags: magento-2.1, database, magento-community

I changed my **admin URL** in the **admin panel** of Magento and now can't get control of **admin URL** I tried with changing from `local.XML` file,

but still **not accessible**.

Answer (score 1):

Login in your site with SSH access

and

Go to Magento root directory

and fire below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean 

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. you are using a linux server
2. you have access to the terminal
3. You have navigated to the installation folder of magento using the terminal

To get your current admin uri, pass command in the terminal:

- bin/magento info:adminuri

To change your admin uri:

- bin/magento setup:config:set--backend-frontname=[put your admin uri here]

Please refer to magento documentation:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-adminurl.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0//install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-deployment.html